# A SuggestBox for wxPython?

Tags: python, search, wxpython, suggestbox

Is there a widget for wxPython like the [SuggestBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/index.html) in Google Web Toolkit? It is basically a magic text box that can invoke some code to come up with suggestions relevant to whatever the user has entered so far. Like the search box on Google's web page.

If such a widget isn't already floating out there, I'd appreciate a sketch of how I might implement it with the existing widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at [Combo Box that Suggests Options](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Combo%20Box%20that%20Suggests%20Options).

I hope this is what you were thinking of.

Comment: Thanks, that is close enough that I'll be able to make what I want. For anyone else reading that page, at the moment it doesn't quite work right when wxWidgets is using GTK. This page: http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/wxpython-users/3652448 has the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Few years ago I made a control like this by subclassing TextCtrl. It supports HTML formating for suggestions. [Here you go.](http://bitbucket.org/raz/wxautocompletectrl)